# query to cut a varchar in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

[image]

I would like to cut all entries in the p_path and remove the "~\"

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE dbo.picture 
  SET p_path = SUBSTRING(p_path, 3, 4000)
  WHERE p_path LIKE '~/%';
```

Comment: Agreed, this is much safer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select replace(p_path,'~\','') as CutPath from table
```

Comment: Note that this will replace any embedded `~/` past the beginning of the string too...

Comment: Now I have '/' in the beginning . how do I remove only the first one?